# HTTP Status Code 411 - Length Required

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, http-status-code-411

I try to get data from server. I use NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate. There is code (Objective - C).

```
-(void)sendRequest
{
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://SomeServer"];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];


NSString* reqBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<tag>Content</tag>"];

NSData* reqData = [reqBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSInputStream* stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:reqData];



[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPBodyStream:stream];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

self.wpData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSURLConnection* conection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[conection start];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    [self.wpData setLength:0];    

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d {
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"RESPONSE DATA: %@",str);
[self.wpData appendData:d];
}
```

But I get "411 - Length Required" when I use

```
[request setHTTPBodyStream:stream];
```

and "HASH (someAddress)" when I use

```
[request setHTTPBody:reqData];
```

I tried

```
[request setHTTPBodyStream:stream];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [reqData length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

but again "HASH (someAdddress)"

What have I done wrong?
Sorry for my English. Thanks :)

Comment: I got the same error when I was doing a `POST` when I should have been doing a `GET`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> What have I done wrong?

Nothing.

HTTP Status Code 411 (Length Required) is sent by the server as a response when it refuses to accept a message without a content-length header, for whatever reason.

A server simply may or may not accept a content without a Content-Length header.

When you set an `NSInputStream` object as request body via property `HTTPBodyStream` for the request, `NSURLConnection` cannot evaluate the length of the body itself anymore. (there is no property `length` for a stream). Hence, `NSURLConnection` uses a certain "transfer mode",  namely "chunked transfer encoding". This transfer mode *should* succeed to transmit any body and it does not require a Content-Legth header (actually *must* not contain one). Alas, the server simply does not accept this type of transfer.

See also: [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) (wiki).

To solve the issue on the client side:

- Determine the length of the body yourself (if possible) and set a "Content-Length" header field for the request. If this input stream has been created from a file or from a `NSData` object, the length can be easily determined. But be sure to set the exact same length as the actual stream content in bytes.
- Don't use a `NSInputStream`, but use a `NSData` object as body and set it via property `HTTPBody`. When you set the body as a `NSData` object, `NSURLConnection` can determine the content length itself, and it will automatically add a Content-Length header with the correct length, unless you set it yourself in the request.